# TYPO3 Login Error

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system, typo3

i installed TYPO3 on my computer, than i moved all files to our server and importet the database.

If i am on the log in screen, the css and javascript is missing...

Now its not possible to log into  the back end. It says "Make sure to spell your username and password correctly, including upper/lowercase characters.".

If i look under sys_log and there are only these logs: Login-attempt from %s (%s) for username '%s' with an empty password!

What should i do? :/

Comment: Are you able to go to the Install Tool? Do you see any issues there?

Comment: i am able to log into the install tool

Comment: look into the network log of your browser and verify that all files are existent and accessible. also check for values containing domain-name. You might have some URLs containing the domain of your first installation.

Comment: So, everything working in the Install Tool? DB connection? Configuration without errors? Caches cleared?

Comment: Euer Username ist deutsch, also schreib ich mal deutsch haha. Also, ich habe mal im Login geschaut, er findet das css und javascript alles nicht... Error 404. Und das obwohl der Pfad stimmt... Nicht mal das favicon.. :P

Comment: Ich habe den Cache bereinigt, den temp ordner gelöscht.. einfach alles versucht... aber es mag nicht. Kann es daran liegen das Strato nicht damit umgehen kann?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the install tool and flush all caches.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have a .htaccess rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]
```

and either remove it or comment it or remove `js` from the list.